# Auto redirect in Laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-5, routes

As a simple example, I am wanting to do the same as StackOverflow with regards to question URL redirect. Here is an example:

If I go to:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092079
```

I get redirected to:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092079/what-exactly-is-laravel
```

I would like to replicate this.

My `routes/web.php` entry is: `Route::get('blog/{id}/{slug}', 'BlogController@show');`.

This works how it says it should but if I navigate without the `slug`, it doesn't redirect.

Would the best way to acheive this be to set the redirect in the controller?

Laravel version: **5.5**

Comment: make the slug optional and check in the controller if it's null or not.

Comment: Sorry @Ali, I think you misinterpret what I am trying to acheive. I would like to 301 redirect to the URL with the slug included if it is not present in the original request

Comment: then make a new method and url for that logic

Comment: @Sohel0415 You seem to have hit the nail on the head. Can you guide me on the right path in an answer please?

Comment: you have to forcefully pass slug and id otherwise it surely redirect because route not find.

Comment: @SachinAghera OK. Can you please explain more in an answer?

Comment: Route::get('blog-without slug/{id}/', 'BlogController@showBlogWithoutSlug');
Route::get('blog/{id}/{slug}', 'BlogController@show');

Comment: make 2 routes one for without slug and one for with slug and there controller

Comment: @SachinAghera Again, this is not what I want. I want to redierect if there is no slug

Comment: write  that logic in your controller

Comment: Possibly post as an answer so that it is a little more clear what you are trying to say? (Also, good for getting rep )

Comment: @Wildcard27 see my answer, it may give you an idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Make `two` `routes`

```
Route::get('blog/{blog}', 'BlogController@redirectWithSlug');
Route::get('blog/{id}/{slug}', 'BlogController@show');
```

And in your `BlogController`

```
public function redirectWithSlug(Blog $blog)
{
    return redirect('blog/'.$blog_id.'/'.$blog->slug);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this with a resource controller?

Comment: yes, you can change your logic of show method with this logic